# Get an image from a flash object

Tags: flash, url

How could you get the image URL from the image that you can download clicking on the right panel (camera icon) of this flash object?

http://www.omie.es/files/flash/ResultadosMercado.swf

When you click on that icon, you get offered to download something like this:

INT_PBC_EV_H_1_27_6_2014_27_6_2014.jpg

What I need is the full URL for this image, so I can play with it from my code.

Thanks so much

Comment: I finally just load the flash object from HTML because what you can see when you open it, is pretty much the image I was trying to download. However, when it opens from HTML, it doesn't have the date loaded so it shows nothing. Don't know what it needs to work properly, if there is any param I'm missing...

Comment: <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="1005" height="740"><param name="flash_component" value="ImageViewer.swc" />
<param name="movie" value="http://www.omie.es/files/flash/ResultadosMercado.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="FlashVars"  />
<embed src="http://www.omie.es/files/flash/ResultadosMercado.swf" quality="high" </embed>
...